Fill Word documents without overwriting base files using VBA macro
I wrote VBA code to fill Word documents based on an Excel table.
The base model Word files get overwritten with the new, filled documents.
I have to replace the model files with empty ones to run it again.
Sub AnexoF_CPFL()

Dim Linha As Integer
Linha = InputBox("Qual a linha do projeto?", "Gerar Anexo F CPFL")

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True

Set arqAnexoF = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Axis\Axis Renováveis Dropbox\Pasta da equipe                Axis Renováveis\Axis Renovaveis Server\4 - Operações\1. Desenvolvimento\2. Prospecção\Consultas de Acesso\Macros\Modelos\CPFL\AnexoF.docx")
Set conteudo = arqAnexoF.Application.Selection

For i = 2 To 25
    conteudo.Find.Text = Cells(1, i).Value
    conteudo.Find.Replacement.Text = Cells(Linha, i).Value
    conteudo.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next

arqAnexoF.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\Axis\Axis Renováveis Dropbox\Pasta da equipe Axis Renováveis\Axis Renovaveis Server\4 - Operações\1. Desenvolvimento\2. Prospecção\Consultas de Acesso\CPFL Paulista\Consultas\" & "Anexo F - " & Cells(Linha, 2), FileFormat:=17

arqAnexoF.Close
objWord.Quit

Set arqAnexoF = Nothing
Set conteudoDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing

MsgBox ("Anexo F CPFL gerado com sucesso!")

End Sub

I tried copying a new file, that then is filled with the information, but it failed.

What if you mark AnexoF.docx as read-only?  Or make it a template https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb

How about moving arqAnexoF.SaveAs2 .. after the Documents.Open .. line, and changing arqAnexoF.Close True (save change before close)?

You really should be using a Word Template for "AnexoF" (i.e. "AnexoF.dotx") instead of an ordinary Word document. Aside from anything else, opening a template via double-clicking for example, creates a new document, thus minimizing the chances of overwriting it. You should also declare all your variables and, since you're using late binding, you need to assign the Word constants before using them (or just use their numeric enumerations). Then you could use code like:
Sub AnexoF_CPFL()
Dim xlSht As Worksheet, objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, Linha As Long, i As Long, StrPath As String
Const wdFindContinue As Long = 1: Const wdReplaceAll As Long = 2: Const wdFormatPDF As Long = 17
Linha = InputBox("Qual a linha do projeto?", "Gerar Anexo F CPFL")
StrPath = "C:\Users\Axis\Axis Renováveis Dropbox\Pasta da equipe Axis Renováveis\Axis Renovaveis Server\" & _
          "4 - Operações\1. Desenvolvimento\2. Prospecção\Consultas de Acesso\"
Set xlSht = ActiveSheet
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(StrPath & "\Macros\Modelos\CPFL\AnexoF.dotx")
With objDoc
  With .Range.Find
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    For i = 2 To 25
      .Text = xlSht.Cells(1, i).Value
      .Replacement.Text = xlSht.Cells(Linha, i).Value
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
  End With
  .SaveAs2 Filename:=StrPath & "CPFL Paulista\Consultas\" & "Anexo F - " & xlSht.Cells(Linha, 2) & ".pdf", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
  .Close
End With
objWord.Quit
Set arqAnexoF = Nothing: Set objWord = Nothing: Set xlSht = Nothing
MsgBox ("Anexo F CPFL gerado com sucesso!")
End Sub

